# I have some sample about jquery autocomplted. In controller i can't receive any empName

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, autocomplete

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var na = $('#empName');
        $("#empName").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                empName = document.getElementById("empName").value;
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Autocompleted","Employees")',
                    type: "POST",
                    datatype: "json",
                    data: { "empName": empName },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("hai");
                    }

                });
            },
            message: {

            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult Autocompleted(string empName)
    {

      var employeename = new[] { "satheesh", "kumar", "raj" };
      var result = employeename.Where(emp => emp.IndexOf(empName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
      return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Ever time autocomplted is called. but my problem is empName value is not recive.only empty value only i got it please any one help me i am new for MVC

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a question

Comment: Now u can understand#cyberooot

Comment: have you tried console logging to see the value of `na` and `empName`? Try `console.log(na)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public JsonResult Autocompleted(string empName)
    {

      var employeename = new[] { "satheesh", "kumar", "raj" };
      var emp_name = employeename.Where(emp => emp.IndexOf(empName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0).AsEnumerable();
       var result = emp_name.Select(a => new
            {
                data = Convert.ToString(a["empName"])
            }).ToList();
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```